# SQL query for calculating Net Promoter Score over time

Tags: mysql, sql, graph

**Background:**

Net Promoter Score is a way to measure a company's performance through the eyes of the customer. The idea is that the customer answers a question on the form "how likely are you to recommend X to a friend or colleague?", on a scale from 0-10. The answers are then grouped into three categories: detractors (0-6), passives (7-8) and promoters (9-10). The NPS can vary between -100 and +100, and is calculated like this:

```
NPS = (% of promoters) - (% of detractors)
```

(Source: http://www.netpromoter.com/np/calculate.jsp)

**Problem:**

I need to plot NPS over time, and ideally if this is achievable through plain SQL. Right now I'm kind of stuck and need help on this.

Let's boil it down and omit all the joins and other related demographic data stuff to the following. I don't think that I would need to track the exact answer, so let's assume I store the answers on this form:

```
answer     date
0          2011-11-28
1          2011-11-30
2          2011-12-02
```

where 0 = detractor, 1 = passive and 2 = promoter.

From this information, I would like to visualize the NPS-value over time, say grouped by date. How could I design such a (My)SQL query, is it even possible without looping and performing multiple queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having that table it's possible to get it in a single query like this:

```
SELECT date, SUM(answer-1) * 100 / COUNT(answer) as NPS
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: That's a good one, it helped to reduce the problem into storing it this way, thanks a lot!